# Print PDF Scaled Down in Top Left Corner

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a PDF that  would print something like the following by default:

```
 __________
| ........ |
| ........ |
| ........ |
| ........ |
|__________|
```

If I scale down the content it remains centered.

```
 __________
|          |
|   ....   |
|   ....   |
|          |
|__________|
```

Is there a way to have the content moved to the top left corner after scaling?

```
 __________
| ....     |
| ....     |
|          |
|          |
|__________|
```

Comment: What app are you printing from?

Comment: Preview. Is there another that would be better?